# At what line can this object be considered to be garbage collected. Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

So my understanding is at line 1, a new object is created and it is referenced by obj. At line 2, obj is referencing to another new object. so the object which we created at line 1 is eligible for garbage collection because it is not referenced by any instance. But the answer from test question is at line 3. Reason? Is the answer correct?

```
Object obj = new Object();  //line 1
obj = new Object();  //line 2
obj = null;  //3
```

Edit: it is asking when the object created at line 1 can be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: What is the actual question? How do you know which object it is referencing?

Comment: Which object are you (or the test) referring to as "this object", though, the one created in line 1 or the one created in line 2? The answer is different. Also, it can't be considered to be "garbage collected" but it can be considered to be "eligible". You use one term in your title and the other in the body of your question. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: No object can be considered to be garbage collected anywhere above.

Comment: @DavidConrad the object at line 1

Comment: With some caveats, the object created on line 1 becomes unreferenced after line 2 is executed.

Comment: Also, is the test asking what line you would be *on* when the object is eligible, or the execution of what line *makes* it eligible? Since it is the execution of line 2 that renders it eligible, depending on how the question is *phrased* I could see either 2 or 3 as the answer. It is only eligible for garbage collection ***after*** line 2.

Comment: @DavidConrad Here is the exact words from the test: Which is the earliest line in the following code after which the object created on line //1 can be garbage collected, assuming no compiler optimizations are done?

Comment: It can only be garbage collected after line 2 has executed. Since the question includes "after which", I think the answer must be line 2.

Comment: Yep, I would say after line 2, and I largely wrote the JVM for IBM iSeries, so I kinda know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world this question (as posed by the title) has no clear answer.

- aggressive dead code elimination could eliminate the first object allocation since it never becomes visible
- a modified Object Class (e.g. via bytecode instrumentation or bootstrap classloaders) could resurrect itself on finalization or hold onto additional references indefinitely
- garbage collection is asynchronous and happens at an indefinite point in the future, so while an object may be inaccessible from java code it cannot be "considered" garbage collected until it actually has been garbage collected.
  It might show up in a heap dump after all, which can be relevant if it contained security-sensitive data

I know it's supposed to be an academic question with a simple answer, but there are so many assumptions to make that I could rule-lawyer you any answer you want into existence.

Even if we don't pull any rabbits out of our hat the answer would still depend on whether "at line X" means before or after the execution of that

Answer (score -2):

The garbage collector is checking for live objects and discarding anything that is not. When you create `obj`, you define it's type because that allows the compiler to know how much space to allot for that address, because something of `Type Object` will exist there. When the second line executes, new is creating an entirely new instance of the object and you are assigning its address to `obj`. So after reassigning `obj` to reference a new object, the old one still exists, but is no longer referenced. It would potentially be marked for collection as it occupies space in the heap, but is no longer active. The same happens with line 3, except, as mentioned previously, you are assigning it an address of `null`, and no new object is being created. So what used to be referenced by `obj` are now dead objects and the garbage man takes them away.

Comment: I probably over-simplified it, but I figured that roughly answers the question.

Comment: so what is the answer? at line 2 or at line 3?

Comment: The size of all references is the same (typically 32 bits, although 64-bit Java may use 64 bits), so the memory reserved for `obj` is the same regardless of its type. The space for the object is only allocated when the object is created, not when the variable is defined. The type referred to by `obj` can be `Object` or any subclass of `Object` -- in other words, any type at all other than a primitive. After the second line,  `obj` is referring to a *different* object, so the first one **is** eligible for garbage collection at that point.

Comment: Once you overwrite the value in `obj` with the new one in line 2, the value set by line 1 is no longer accessible.

Comment: The `new Object()` in line 2 creates a (duh!) *new* object, using space different from the one created in line 1.  Both objects "exist" simultaneously, even after the reference to the first object is overwritten (though how long after is hard to predict).

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, I know. I was already editing after re-reading.

Comment: @HotLicks either way, both are eligible for garbage collection. :D

Comment: @taimeili123 If you are asking when the object created at line 1 is eligible for collection, it would be as soon as it  is no longer referenced, which would be after the execution of line 2. If you want to know when it is collected, I don't know. When ever the Garbage collector does it's sweep, it will go and collected eligible objects in memory.

Comment: I would suggest that instead of answering in comments, post it as an answer and let taimeili select it.

Comment: The first sentence suggests that garbage collection has some other, secondary purpose. Such as what? The second sentence in the first paragraph is both wrong and irrelevant and should be deleted. Ditto the struck-out third sentence. The edit shoudl be incorporated properly into the answer, instead of presenting a 'rephrasing', which it actually isn't.